# How can i retrieve a returned value with the "ExecuteScriptAsync" method in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, cefsharp, c#-to-vb.net

I am using CefSharp as a browser in a VB.net application and i want to retrieve a return value from the browser.

I only find solutions in C#, but i can't make it work in VisualBasic.

In this code i get the following error: 'Error: Result is not a member of Task'

```vb
Dim script = "var returnValue = function(){ var value; value=10-2; return value; }"
        Dim task As Threading.Tasks.Task = browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script)
        Dim taskResult As String

        task.ContinueWith(Sub(t)
                              If t.IsFaulted = False Then
                                  Dim response = t.Result 'Error: Result is not a member of Task' 
                                  If response.Success And response.Result IsNot Nothing Then
                                      taskResult = response.Result
                                  End If
                              End If
                          End Sub)

        MsgBox(taskResult)
```

And this is the C# version that i find in the CefSharp documentation, but i can't translate it to VB.net:

```cs
browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script).ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            var response = x.Result;

            if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
            {
                var onePlusOne = (int)response.Result;
                //Do something here (To interact with the UI you must call BeginInvoke)
            }      
        });
```

Comment: `Dim task As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of JavascriptResponse) = ...` or just omit the type and let it infer it correctly. Also, `&&` translates to `AndAlso`.

Comment: @madreflection Thank you for your answer. With the Task(Of JavascriptResponse) now it runs, but unfortunately i doesn't get the return value :/

Comment: You have assigned the result to a variable,  remove var returnValue = and just execute the anon closure.

Comment: Please ignore any suggestion that ContinueWith is not needed, using Task.Result directly will result in a blocking operation and you can easily end up with a deadlock see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks

Comment: Rewriting the code to use await instead of ContinueWith is perfectly acceptable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/await-operator

Comment: @RobertBaron Calling Task.Wait is also blocking, you have rewritten Async code and made it synchronous. Please use your favorite search engine to search for Task.Wait deadlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your Javascript so that it returns a value. As suggested in the comments, I changed the declaration of `task` to correct the error you mentioned.

```
Dim script = "(function(){ var value; value=10-2; return value; })();"
Dim task As Task(Of JavascriptResponse) = browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script)
Dim taskResult As String

task.ContinueWith(
    Sub(t)
        If t.IsFaulted = False Then
            Dim response = t.Result 'Error: Result is not a member of Task' 
            If response.Success And response.Result IsNot Nothing Then
                taskResult = response.Result
            End If
        End If
    End Sub)

MsgBox(task.Result.Result)
```

Comment: Directly calling Task.Result outside of the ContinueWith will result in the call being blocking, see my link in the original question. MsgBox should be called on the UI thread, you can have the continuation using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ContinueWith_System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_ and passing in

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_FromCurrentSynchronizationContext only works of invoked from the UI thread

Comment: Thank you, i changed 'Task(Of JavascriptResponse)'  to 'Threading.Tasks.Task(Of JavascriptResponse)' in your code and it finally worked!
Thanks to everyone who answered!

Answer (score -1):

```
    Dim html As String = ""
    Using t As Task(Of String) = WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML;")
        Do Until t.IsCompleted
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        html = t.Result
    End Using
    html = Regex.Unescape(html)
    html = html.Remove(0, 1)
    html = html.Remove(html.Length - 1, 1)
    html = html.Replace("<!--!-->", "")
```